# Svelte Store and Asynchronous Local Storage (CapacitorJS' Preferences plugin)

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, svelte, capacitor

I have a custom store that works with synchronous localStorage. I would like to use capacitorjs' preferences plugin but it is asynchronous. My code looks like this:

useStorage.js

```
const getItem = async (key) => {
    const { value } = await Preferences.get({ key: key });

    return value;
};

const setItem = async (key, value) => {
    await Preferences.set({
        key,
        value
    });
};

export function localStore(key, defaultValue) {
let serialize = JSON.stringify;
let deserialize = JSON.parse;

let storedValue;

const { subscribe, update, set } = writable(storedValue || defaultValue);
subscribe((value) => setItem(key, serialize(value)));

return {
    subscribe,
    async function() {
        const item = deserialize(await getItem(key));
        storedValue = item;
    },
    set
};
```

}

stores.js

```
export const name = localStore('name', 'your name');
```

Now what happens is updating $name to another value also updates it on localStorage. But when I reload, it reverts back to the default value since it takes time to get the storedValue. Does anyone know a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

```
1.First install
npm install @capacitor/preferences
npx cap sync

2.Then import
import { Preferences } from "@capacitor/preferences";

3.React js Code
let [step, setStep] = useState(1);

const setCpaStep = async (step) => {
    await Preferences.set({
        key: "capStep",
        value: step,
    });
};

const getCpaStep = async () => {
    const { value } = await Preferences.get({ key: "capStep" 
});
    const result = JSON.parse(value);
    console.log(`Step ${Number(result)}`);
    return Number(result);
};

const nextPage = () => {
    setStep((current) => current + 1);
    //localStorage.setItem("step", step + 1);
    setCpaStep(getCpaStep() + step);
};

const prevPage = () => {
    setStep((current) => current - 1);
    //localStorage.setItem("step", step - 1);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

[svelte-capacitor-store](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svelte-capacitor-store)

```
import { writable, type Writable } from "svelte/store";
import { Preferences } from '@capacitor/preferences';
import { Capacitor } from '@capacitor/core';

const isDeviceNative = Capacitor.isNativePlatform();

export type ArrayStoreInputType<T> = {
  storeName: string,
  initialValue: T,
  initFunction?: () => void,
  validationStatement?: (value: T) => boolean
}

export function arrayStore<T>({ storeName, initialValue, initFunction, validationStatement }: ArrayStoreInputType<T>) {

  let storeValueInitialized = false
  let currentStoreValue: T = initialValue

  const { subscribe, update, set } = writable(initialValue, () => {
    if (typeof window === 'undefined') return
    setTimeout(async () => {
      let storedValue: T | null
      if (isDeviceNative) {
        storedValue = await getCapacitorStore(storeName) as T | null
      } else {
        storedValue = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(storeName) || 'null') as T | null
      }

      storeValueInitialized = true

      if (Array.isArray(storedValue)) {
        validationStatement ? customSet(storedValue) : set(storedValue)
      }
      if (initFunction) initFunction()
    }, 0);
  }) as Writable<T>;

  const customUpdate = (callback: (value: T) => T): void => {
    const newValue = callback(currentStoreValue);
    customSet(newValue)
  };

  const customSet = (value: T): void => {
    if (typeof window === 'undefined' || !value || !Array.isArray(value) || !value.length || !value?.[0]) return
    if (validationStatement && !validationStatement(value)) return
    set(value);
    currentStoreValue = value

  };

  function customSubscribe(callback: (value: T, lastValue: T) => void) {
    let lastStoreValue: T = initialValue;
    return subscribe((value: T) => {
      const lastValue = structuredClone(lastStoreValue);
      lastStoreValue = value;
      return callback(value, lastValue);
    });
  }

  customSubscribe(async (value: T, lastValue: T) => {
    if (typeof window === 'undefined' || !storeValueInitialized || !value || !Array.isArray(value) || !value.length || !value?.[0]) return
    if (validationStatement && !validationStatement(value)) { customSet(lastValue ?? initialValue); return }

    if (isDeviceNative) await setCapacitorStore({ key: storeName, value: value })
    else localStorage.setItem(storeName, JSON.stringify(value));

  });

  return {
    subscribe: customSubscribe,
    update: validationStatement ? customUpdate : update,
    set: validationStatement ? customSet : set,

    reset: async (): Promise<void> => {
      if (typeof window === 'undefined') return
      set(initialValue)
      if (isDeviceNative) await setCapacitorStore({ key: storeName, value: initialValue })
      else localStorage.setItem(storeName, JSON.stringify(initialValue));
    },
    getValue: async (): Promise<T | null> => {
      let storedValue: T | null
      if (isDeviceNative) {
        storedValue = await getCapacitorStore(storeName) as T | null
      } else {
        storedValue = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(storeName) || 'null') as T | null
      }

      if (Array.isArray(storedValue)) {
        validationStatement ? customSet(storedValue) : set(storedValue)
        return storedValue
      }

      return null
    }

  }
}



export type ObjectStoreInputType<T> = {
  storeName: string, initialValue: T, initFunction?: () => void, validationStatement?: (value: T) => boolean
}

export function objectStore<T>({ storeName, initialValue, initFunction, validationStatement }: ObjectStoreInputType<T>) {
  let storeValueInitialized = false
  let currentStoreValue: T = initialValue

  const { subscribe, update, set } = writable(initialValue, () => {
    if (typeof window === 'undefined') return
    setTimeout(async () => {
      let storedValue: T | null
      if (isDeviceNative) {
        storedValue = await getCapacitorStore(storeName) as T | null
      } else {
        storedValue = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(storeName) || 'null') as T | null
      }

      storeValueInitialized = true

      if (storedValue) {
        validationStatement ? customSet(storedValue) : set(storedValue)
      }

      if (initFunction) initFunction()
    }, 0);
  }) as Writable<T>;

  const customUpdate = (callback: (value: T) => T): void => {
    const newValue = callback(currentStoreValue);
    customSet(newValue)
  };

  const customSet = (value: T): void => {
    console.log("customSet", { value })
    if (typeof window === 'undefined' || !value) return
    if (validationStatement && !validationStatement(value)) return
    set(value);
    currentStoreValue = value
  };

  function customSubscribe(callback: (value: T, lastValue: T) => void) {
    let lastStoreValue: T = initialValue;
    return subscribe((value: T) => {
      const lastValue = structuredClone(lastStoreValue);
      lastStoreValue = value;
      return callback(value, lastValue);
    });
  }

  customSubscribe(async (value: T, lastValue) => {
    if (typeof window === 'undefined' || !storeValueInitialized || !value) return
    if (validationStatement && !validationStatement(value)) { customSet(lastValue ?? initialValue); return }

    if (isDeviceNative) await setCapacitorStore({ key: storeName, value: value })
    else localStorage.setItem(storeName, JSON.stringify(value));

  });


  return {
    subscribe: customSubscribe,
    update: validationStatement ? customUpdate : update,
    set: validationStatement ? customSet : set,

    reset: async (): Promise<void> => {
      if (typeof window === 'undefined') return
      set(initialValue)
      if (isDeviceNative) await setCapacitorStore({ key: storeName, value: initialValue })
      else localStorage.setItem(storeName, JSON.stringify(initialValue));
    },

    getValue: async (): Promise<T | null> => {
      let storedValue: T | null
      if (isDeviceNative) {
        storedValue = await getCapacitorStore(storeName) as T | null
      } else {
        storedValue = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(storeName) || 'null') as T | null
      }

      if (storedValue) {
        validationStatement ? customSet(storedValue) : set(storedValue)
        return storedValue
      }

      return null
    }

  }
}



export type VariableStoreInputType<T> = {
  storeName: string, initialValue: T, initFunction?: () => void, validationStatement?: (value: T) => boolean
}

export function variableStore<T>({ storeName, initialValue, initFunction, validationStatement }: VariableStoreInputType<T>) {
  let storeValueInitialized = false
  let currentStoreValue: T = initialValue

  const { subscribe, update, set } = writable(initialValue, () => {
    if (typeof window === 'undefined') return
    setTimeout(async () => {
      let storedValue: T | null
      if (isDeviceNative) {
        storedValue = await getCapacitorStore(storeName) as T | null
      } else {
        storedValue = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(storeName) || 'null') as T | null
      }

      storeValueInitialized = true
      if (storedValue !== null && storedValue !== undefined && typeof storedValue === typeof initialValue) {
        validationStatement ? customSet(storedValue) : set(storedValue)
        return
      }

      if (initFunction) initFunction()
    }, 100);
  }) as Writable<T>;
  const customUpdate = (callback: (value: T) => T): void => {
    const newValue = callback(currentStoreValue);
    customSet(newValue)
  };

  const customSet = (value: T): void => {
    if (typeof window === 'undefined' || (validationStatement && !validationStatement(value))) return
    set(value);
    currentStoreValue = value
  };

  function customSubscribe(callback: (value: T, lastValue: T) => void) {
    let lastStoreValue: T = initialValue;
    return subscribe((value: T) => {
      const lastValue = structuredClone(lastStoreValue);
      lastStoreValue = value;
      return callback(value, lastValue);
    });
  }


  customSubscribe(async (value: T, lastValue: T) => {
    if (typeof window === 'undefined' || !storeValueInitialized) return
    if (validationStatement && !validationStatement(value)) { customSet(lastValue ?? initialValue); return }

    if (isDeviceNative) await setCapacitorStore({ key: storeName, value: value })
    else localStorage.setItem(storeName, JSON.stringify(value));

  });

  return {
    subscribe: customSubscribe,
    update: validationStatement ? customUpdate : update,
    set: validationStatement ? customSet : set,

    reset: async (): Promise<void> => {
      if (typeof window === 'undefined') return
      set(initialValue)
      if (isDeviceNative) await setCapacitorStore({ key: storeName, value: initialValue })
      else localStorage.setItem(storeName, JSON.stringify(initialValue));
    },

    getValue: async (): Promise<T | null> => {
      let storedValue: T | null
      if (isDeviceNative) {
        storedValue = await getCapacitorStore(storeName) as T | null
      } else {
        storedValue = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(storeName) || 'null') as T | null
      }

      if (typeof storedValue === typeof initialValue && storedValue !== null) {
        validationStatement ? customSet(storedValue) : set(storedValue)
        return storedValue
      }

      return null
    }

  }
}

async function getCapacitorStore(key: string) {
  try {
    if (typeof window === 'undefined' || !isDeviceNative) return null

    const result = await Preferences.get({ key });
    const value = result.value;
    return value ? JSON.parse(value) : null;
  } catch (error) {
    // console.error(`Error at getStore function, key: ${key}.`, { error });
    return null
  }
}

async function setCapacitorStore({ key, value }: { key: string, value: any }) {
  try {
    if (typeof window === 'undefined' || !isDeviceNative) return
    await Preferences.set({ key, value: JSON.stringify(value) });
  } catch (error) {
    // console.error(`Error at setStore function, key: ${key}.`, { error });
  }
}
```

This gives you 3 cross-platform stores: variableStore, objectStore, arrayStore, that would work with capcitor storage on native devices and localStorage otherwise, with custom data validation options.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Just little modification to your original function.

```
export async function localStore(key, defaultValue) { // async function to get initial value from storage
    let serialize = JSON.stringify;
    let deserialize = JSON.parse;
    
    let storedValue = deserialize(await getItem(key)); // get initial value from storage
    
    const { subscribe, update, set } = writable(storedValue || defaultValue);
    subscribe((value) => setItem(key, serialize(value)));
    
    return {
        subscribe,
        // async function() {
        //  const item = deserialize(await getItem(key)); // not sure if what this function is supposed to do
        //  storedValue = item;
        // },
        set
    };
}

const name = await localStore('name', 'your name'); // will hydrate from storage  and set default value if not found
```

Comment: Could you explain what you did modify?